# Perl's autosplit function with in place editing

Tags: perl, inplace-editing

I just had a task in where I needed to replace each 3rd value in a tabulator separated file with a fixed value. I guess it can be done in Perl on a Unix shell like so

```
$perl -a -n -i  -F'/\t/' -e '$F[2]="THE FIXED VALUE";print join "\t", @F' bla.txt
```

I just wanted to know if this is a "correct" way, or if there is a better (for a currently lacking definition of better) to do it?

Comment: Perl users like to say "a correct way" rather than "the correct way", but your little script looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your one-liner is reasonable and readable. There are many more ways to do it. I would stack the perlrun options and save a few keystrokes:

```
perl -F'\t' -i -ape'$F[2]="THE FIXED VALUE"; $_ = join "\t", @F' bla.txt
```

A shame that `$,` does not get populated with the argument of `-F`, so there's still a piece of repetition.